# Are these messages/texts usual when bootup/shutdown ubuntu22.04? How can I hide them?

Tags: shutdown

I'm using a dual boot on my laptop, Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04.
When I boot/shutdown my Ubuntu, some messages/texts show on screen.

The first picture shows my laptop config.
[image: the first pic, my Ubuntu config]

The second picture shows what I see when I boot up my Ubuntu, following grub and followed by Ubuntu icon. These messages began to show on screen when boot up, not long after I have set up my dual OS.
[image: the second pic, what I see when bootup and shutdown]

The third picture shows what I see when I shutdown Ubuntu. However, it didn't show before, it just began to show recently, maybe after I changed my grub theme several days ago. Someone told me that it's so-called kernel panic. And the messages in picture 2 began to show together, firstly.
[image: the third pic, what I see when shutdown]

By the way, all my system works just well currently.

I wonder if other Ubuntu/Linux users see such messages/texts when boot/shutdown?

Do these messages matter?

If these don't matter, what can I do to make these not shown?

Edit:
After I update my linux kernel from 6.2 to 6.5, almost all those messages disappear, only left these two lines:
[image: the only left messages]